# String.fromCharCode got different results between browser and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

I had trouble using String.fromCharCode in JavaScript(I used it in browser and nodejs), When the parameter was less than 128, I got the same result, but when it was over 128, the result of nodejs was wrong.
here is the code and the result
in browser:

```
window.btoa(String.fromCharCode(127))
```

in nodejs:

```
Buffer.from(String.fromCharCode(127)).toString('base64')
```

[code & result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMPFH.png)

so, how can I get the right result with nodejs code?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Could you please copy and paste the output rather than posting an image ? It will greatly improve the quality of your question. If you have any question, refer to the  [how to ask section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the `Buffer.from()` call you have to pass `"binary"` as the second parameter:

```
Buffer.from(String.fromCharCode(127), "binary").toString('base64')
```